# Order search results

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I recently added the searching books feature to my application. Now, I would like to add a sorting feature but I struggle to do it. What I want to achieve:
When I do not search for any book title I want to be able to sort books by their price or title on the book/index. However, if I use the search feature I would like to be able to sort the found books by price or title. Can someone help me or guide me on how to do it and combine it with my current code? I attach my current code for searching, and the form I have for the sorting feature.

The search bar is placed in layout/app.html.eex

book/index.html.eex - Sorting form at the top

```
<%= f = form_for @conn, book_path(@conn, :index), [method: :get, as: "order_and_filter"], fn f-> %>
  <% options = ["Order by": "", "Title": "title_asc", "Title (Desc)": "title_desc",
                "Price": "price_asc", "Price (Desc)": "price_desc"] %>
  <%= select f, :order_by, options, class: "tag-select tag-select-sm" %>
  <%= submit "Sort" %>
<% end %>
</form>
<div class="grid sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-5 gap-x-10 gap-y-10 p-6 ">
  <%= for book <- @books do %>
    <%= link to: Routes.book_path(@conn, :show, book) do %>
    <div
      class="flex flex-col justify-between w-60 sm:w-60 h-80 bg-white bg-center text-gray-800 shadow-md overflow-hidden cursor-pointer rounded-md"
      style='background-image: url("<%= book_img_without_img_tag(book, :thumbnail) %>"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;'>
      <div class="flex justify-between items-center ml-4 pr-8">
      </div>
      <div class="bg-white bg-opacity-95 shadow-md rounded-r-xl p-4 flex flex-col mr-4 mb-8">
        <h3 class="truncate text-s font-bold pb-2"><%= book.title %></h3>
        <p class="truncate text-gray-500 text-sm"><%= full_name(book.author) %></p>
        <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
          <span class="text-gray-400 text-xs">£<%= book.original_price %></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Schema and query:

```
  schema "books" do
    field(:description, :string)
    field(:image_url, BookstoreWeb.Uploaders.ImageUploader.Type)
    field(:isbn, :string)
    field(:original_price, :float)
    field(:title, :string)
    field(:slug, :string)
    field(:year_published, :integer)
    field(:quantity, :integer)

[OTHER CODE]

  def search(query, search_term) do
    wildcard_search = "%#{search_term}%"

    from(b in query,
      join: a in assoc(b, :author),
      where: fragment("? % ?", b.title, ^wildcard_search),
      or_where: ilike(b.description, ^wildcard_search),
      or_where: ilike(a.last_name, ^wildcard_search),
      or_where: ilike(a.first_name, ^wildcard_search),
      order_by: fragment("similarity(?, ?) DESC", b.title, ^wildcard_search)
    )
  end
```

Inventory.ex

```
  def list_books(params) do
    search_term = get_in(params, ["query"])

    Book
    |> Book.search(search_term)
    |> preload(:category)
    |> preload(:author)
    |> Repo.all()
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the case when `pattern matching` helps you.
I recommend you to add code below to match case of empty string with ordering there and in case of some value in search get rid of ordering if I understand you properly

```
  def search(query, "") do # change there
    wildcard_search = "%#{""}%"

    from(b in query,
      join: a in assoc(b, :author),
      where: fragment("? % ?", b.title, ^wildcard_search),
      or_where: ilike(b.description, ^wildcard_search),
      or_where: ilike(a.last_name, ^wildcard_search),
      or_where: ilike(a.first_name, ^wildcard_search),
      order_by: fragment("similarity(?, ?) DESC", b.title, ^wildcard_search)
    )
  end
  def search(query, search_term) do
    wildcard_search = "%#{search_term}%"

    from(b in query,
      join: a in assoc(b, :author),
      where: fragment("? % ?", b.title, ^wildcard_search),
      or_where: ilike(b.description, ^wildcard_search),
      or_where: ilike(a.last_name, ^wildcard_search),
      or_where: ilike(a.first_name, ^wildcard_search)
      # removed order by here
    )
  end
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply and the advice. However, what I do not know is how to write sorting functionality. What I mean is that there are two scenarios. First, when I go to index page I want to sort books desc/asc by price/title. Second, after I search for a book and all matching results are displayed I would like to sort results desc/asc by price/title.